# Stored procedure that executes nodeJS file

Tags: node.js, sql-server, stored-procedures

Everything I can find related to the title deals with having a NodeJS program that calls a stored procedure.

**My question**: is it possible to do the reverse? Have a stored procedure that calls/executes a NodeJS file/program? Working on a project where our database will provide some data (a few ints and a string) and then essentially send the results to a NodeJS program that enters the data into a web page form.

We are hoping to have the stored procedure provide nodeJS with the data directly as opposed to our initial thought of sending the data into a batch file that then calls nodeJS and passes in the data that way in order to reduce the steps and potential breaking points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to do the reverse? Have a stored procedure that calls/executes a NodeJS file/program?

Possible, yes, but it wouldn't really "reduce the steps and potential breaking points.".  You'd have to have the stored procedure launch an external process on the SQL Server that runs the nodeJS code.  There's not built-in nodeJS extensibility in SQL Server like there is with .NET, Python, R, and Java, so you'd have to use `xp_cmdshell`, [sp_start_job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-start-job-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), SSIDB, or one of those other languages to launch the external program.

The best pattern here is to have the stored procedure write the data into some table, and have the external program consume it and do whatever.  For instance you can have the NodeJS running on an application server poll for new data.

Comment: gotcha, so in this case, someone else is heading up the idea to call within the stored procedure and I'm focusing mostly on the nodeJS side.

 If I've set my nodeJS code to set variables equal to respective positions in the process.argv array which are passed in via the command line prompt when the nodeJS file is called, then it likely wouldn't matter if we used the stored procedure or not on my end, as either way it would entail a shell being called with (for example) the command `node index1.js 1 2` would you agree with that thought?

Comment: If the call is coming directly from a stored procedure then the remote SQL Server client is waiting for your NodeJS program to complete, which could cause them a problem, and raises the bar for reliability and error handling for you.  And you would have to install and run your NodeJS code directly on the SQL Server which is not really a great idea.